# df reports 100% full filesystem, du shows only 25% used even though there's no unlinked file

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I have strange issue, `df` shows rootfs is 100% full but `du` shows it's 25% used. So I check on the unlinked files from the rootfs using `lsof +aL1 /` and it does not show me any deleted/unlinked files from rootfs. I tried `find /proc/*/fd -ls | grep  '(deleted)'` too and it does not show any unlinked file from rootfs!

Inode usage is only at 9%

Comment: Can you post the outputs of both `df -l` and `du -s /`?

Comment: Use a bind mount to check for files hidden under other mountpoints.

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks a lot, I was able to figure out the file after doing a bind-mount. Could you make it an Answer so I can select it and upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, a `bind mount` might hide files and directories from the `du` command. But there might be something else as well...

The following might be revealing:

```
% strace -e statfs df /         
statfs("/", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=6288727, f_bfree=4705740, f_bavail=4380531, f_files=1605632, f_ffree=1412254, f_fsid={1878967121, -50608953}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       25154908 6331948  17522124  27% /
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note that there is a difference between `f_bfree` and `f_bavail`. From `man statfs`:

```
fsblkcnt_t f_bfree;   /* Free blocks in filesystem */
fsblkcnt_t f_bavail;  /* Free blocks available to
                         unprivileged user */
```

The `Used` column is based on a calculation: it is total block count - free block count.